# React-native dynamically generated TouchableHighlight with image

Tags: image, react-native, touchablehighlight

I have a form which the user can select one of three options for membership. I an render the screen correctly but the button toggle isn't working. When I click on the other buttons the tick still stays on the first option. Here is my code

```
<View style={styles.mainview}>
          <ListView
            dataSource={this.state.dataSource}
            renderRow={(rowData) =>
              <TouchableHighlight onPress={() => this.toggleOneYear(rowData.id, rowData.i)} style={styles.registerButton} underlayColor='#ffffff'>
                <View style={styles.detailBoxTick}>
                  {renderIf(rowData.i == 1)(
                    <Image style={styles.imageTickStyle} source={this.state.payoneyear ? Images.rememberTickImg : Images.rememberUnTickImg} />
                  )}
                  {renderIf(rowData.i == 2)(
                    <Image style={styles.imageTickStyle} source={this.state.paytwoyear ? Images.rememberTickImg : Images.rememberUnTickImg} />
                  )}
                  {renderIf(rowData.i == 3)(
                    <Image style={styles.imageTickStyle} source={this.state.paythreeyear ? Images.rememberTickImg : Images.rememberUnTickImg} />
                  )}
                  <Text style={styles.tickBoxText}>
                    {rowData.card_duration} years Membership ${rowData.price}
                  </Text>
                </View>
              </TouchableHighlight>
            }
            enableEmptySections
          />
        </View>

toggleOneYear(id, counter) {

    if (counter == 1) {
      console.log('counter ', counter)
      console.log('payoneyear ', this.state.payoneyear)
      this.setState(
        {
          payoneyear: true,
          paytwoyear: false,
          paythreeyear: false
        }
      )
      console.log('payoneyear ', this.state.payoneyear)
    }
    else if (counter == 2) {
      console.log('counter ', counter)
      console.log('payoneyear ', this.state.paytwoyear)
      this.setState(
        {
          payoneyear: false,
          paytwoyear: true,
          paythreeyear: false
        }
      )
      console.log('paytwoyear ', this.state.paytwoyear)
    }
    else if (counter == 3) {
      console.log('counter ', counter)
      this.setState(
        {
          payoneyear: false,
          paytwoyear: false,
          paythreeyear: true
        }
      )
    }
  }
```

What am I doing wrong in the above code? can some one please help. thanks in advance

Comment: Where do you change / set 'counter'?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like you need to update the `dataSource` with new rowData. I guess you are trying to increment `rowData.i` with each touchableHighlight onPress?

The 3rd parameter of renderRow is `rowID`. We will need this to know which row we need to update. You can pass it to `toggleOneYear` or put the following in TouchableHighlight onPress:

```
  var newArray = this.state.db.slice();
  newArray[rowID] = {
    // increment i, keep between 1-3
    i: newArray[rowID].i + 1 > 3 ? 1 : newArray[rowID].i + 1,
  };
  this.setState({
      dataSource: this.state.dataSource.cloneWithRows(newArray),
      db: newArray,
  });
```

I'm unsure what your intentions are with the `payxxxyear` state variables as those are only 3 properties and you are rendering list data so I assume you have many TouchableHighlights that will be using same state. Seems it should probably use data source state instead?

BTW, ListView has been deprecated in latest RN versions. https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/listview.html#renderrow

Comment: Awesome thanks for your help. Solved my issue. I had to create a Boolean in the datasource and update that when one of the other button is clicked.